# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00979

I am performing the following request and I get a "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" error.

```
select distinct 
field1, 
field2, 
field3, 
count(*) as field4, 
field5, 
field6,
case
when smt1>0 then 'Deleted'
when smt2>0 then 'Impacted'
when smt3>0 then 'Unknown'
else 'Clean'
end as field7, 
field8, 
field9, 
field10,
field11, 
field12, 
field13
from (<here a big sub query>) A
group by field1, field2
order by field1, field2
```

I know that I have to put all columns of the SELECT in the GROUP BY statement except the grouping functions ones (like MAX or SUM) so I'm trying the following query but I get the same error message:

```
select distinct 
field1, 
field2, 
field3, 
count(*) as field4, 
field5, 
field6,
case
when smt1>0 then 'Deleted'
when smt2>0 then 'Impacted'
when smt3>0 then 'Unknown'
else 'Clean'
end as field7, 
field8, 
field9, 
field10,
field11, 
field12, 
field13
from (<here a big sub query>) A
group by field1, field2, field3, field5, field6, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13
order by field1, field2
```

How can I solve that without changing the overall meaning of the query?

Thank you very much,
Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing `field7` in your `group by` expression.

Also you cannot use alias in your group by expression of same query. You need to add complete `CASE` statement in your group by expression to include field7.

Just mentioning an alias is not possible in group by, because the `SELECT` step is the last step to happen the execution of a query, grouping happens earlier, when alias names are not yet defined.

Comment: If I'm adding it, I'm getting the following error: ORA-00904: "field7": invalid identifier

Comment: @MartinMoizard - I think you might not be able to add alias in group by of same query. You need to add your complete CASE statement in group by.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag - Yes it is working, do you know why I don't need to write the 'as field7' part of the CASE statement in my GROUP BY statement?

Comment: @MartinMoizard - Explained why you cant use alias in group by in any updated answer.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag - I am not sure to understand what you mean. Can you explain it in another way?

Comment: @MartinMoizard - Lets just say its restriction for Group by and Having clauses. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: The reason you don't need to add the `as field7` part is because that is an alias, which is only allowed in the SELECT part, not in GROUP BY or HAVING or other parts

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the expression

```
case
when smt1>0 then 'Deleted'
when smt2>0 then 'Impacted'
when smt3>0 then 'Unknown'
else 'Clean'
end
```

into your `group by` expression.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can you explain me why I need to put that in the GROUP BY expression?